# What is the correct way to implement cursor inside procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-cursor

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updstock (IN item_id int, IN issue_qty int)

proc_label:
BEGIN

    DECLARE av_stock INT DEFAULT NULL;  
    SET av_stock = (
        select
            sum(qty)
        from
            master_stock
        where
            item_id = item_id
    );

    IF av_stock < issue_qty THEN
    BEGIN
        LEAVE proc_label;
    END

    DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE result CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            id, qty
        FROM
            master_stock
        WHERE
            item_id = item_id
        ORDER BY
            id;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN result;

result_loop:
    LOOP

        FETCH result INTO in_id, in_qty;
    
        IF finished = 1 THEN LEAVE result_loop;
        END IF;

        IF issue_qty <= av_stock THEN
        BEGIN
            UPDATE
                master_stock 
            SET
                qty = qty - issue_qty
            WHERE
                id = in_id
    
            SET issue_qty = 0
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE
                master_stock
            SET
                qty = 0
            WHERE
                id = in_id

            SET issue_qty = issue_qty - av_stock
        END

    END LOOP result_loop;

close result;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have tried above code by referring different articles but still the code showing error which I am unable to resolve. This code is for updating stock in the table using FIFO method.

There are multiple entries for the same product id in the table. The quantity of the `productid` will get updated according to stock available

Comment: ...may I ask what led you to believe you need to use a `CURSOR` here? (I'm asking because invariably `CURSOR`s are a _bad idea_: they're an _ancient_ RDMBS feature that largely exists only for compatibility with _ye-decades-olde_ non-SQL-based OLTP applications (y'know: stuff that predates ODBC) - Also, what version of MySQL are you using (and why aren't you using Postgres?)

Comment: please add version and what error are you getting?

Comment: I am using cursor because as i said that i need to update the quantity column according to the ordered quantity and availability of quality in different batches. I am using version 10.4

Comment: I am using version 10.4 - there isn't a 10.4 version of mysql - maybe you are using mariadb please publish result of select version();

Comment: In mysql and mariadb declare statements must appear immediately after a BEGIN, You also seem to be using parameter names that are the same as column names - this is a bad thing. You should publish the error message in full and provide sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: DECLARE statements must be the most first statements in the code block. You cannot put any other statements before them whereas you declare variable, cursor and handler after a lot of other statements (SET, IF, LEAVE). Either move all declarations to the top of code block or add nested code block.

Comment: PS. While reporting about errors you must provide complete and unchanged error messages.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE result CURSOR FOR SELECT id, qty
FROM master_stock
WHERE item_id = ...' at line 12 - Error I am getting

Comment: Already covered by 2 comments..

Comment: _"I am using cursor because as i said that i need to update the quantity column according to the ordered quantity and availability of quality in different batches."_ - you don't need a `CURSOR` for that - you can use `UPDATE` as a set-based operation (with a CTE, too, if necessary).